# pixel font size in imagettftext instead of point size

Tags: php, gd

I'm trying to use imagettftext, but apparently it uses point size in GD2, but all of my sizes are in pixels, is there any other function that I can use, or any way to convert pixels to points ?

Comment: It seems like it will depend on what GD internally thinks of as the DPI of the image. For example, if the image is 72 DPI, then points are the same as pixels, because 1 point = 1/72 inch. I've been searching for information on whether GD has a DPI setting and how to access it, but no joy so far.

Comment: Just found this PHP bug report that's really old (2002) but seems to have some useful discussion on this issue: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=15656 According to one of the commenters, GD's internal DPI is 96. This squares with my trial-and-error experience trying to match GD's rendered fonts with a PSD file set at 72 DPI. Usually, multiplying the point size from the PSD by 0.75 will get the right size to pass to GD. And 72/96 = 0.75.

Answer (score 10):

If you're super-lazy, then this might work as an approximation:

```
$fontsizeinPT = ($fontsizeinPX*3)/4;
```

Comment: yes, i am super lazy, thanks sir great!

Answer (score 1):

See http://reeddesign.co.uk/test/points-pixels.html