# What is the correct way to determine text coordinates a from bounding box?

Tags: php, text, gd, bounding-box

Given the result of a call to [`imagettfbbox()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagettfbbox.php), what is the correct, pixel-perfect point to provide to [`imagettftext()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php) such that the text will not extend beyond its bounding box?

I am determining the width/height and x/y of the baseline from the bounding box like this:

```
$box = imagettfbbox($size, $angle, $font, $text);
$boxXCoords = array($box[0], $box[2], $box[4], $box[6]);
$boxYCoords = array($box[1], $box[3], $box[5], $box[7]);
$boxWidth = max($boxXCoords) - min($boxXCoords);
$boxHeight = max($boxYCoords) - min($boxYCoords);
$boxBaseX = abs(min($boxXCoords));
$boxBaseY = abs(min($boxYCoords));
```

I then draw a filled rectangle on my image of the dimensions of the bounding box:

```
imagefilledrectangle($image, 0, 0, $boxWidth - 1, $boxHeight - 1, $color);
```

After that, I draw the text:

```
imagettftext($image, $size, $angle, $boxBaseX, $boxBaseY, $color, $font, $text);
```

However, this causes the text to extend beyond the rectangle by a pixel or two.  I have seen several attempts to fix this issue on PHP's `imagettfbbox()` documentation, but they all just suggest substracting a pixel or two here and there, which seems like a hack to me.  What's happening here, and why should we need to fudge the numbers to get things right?

Comment: This is obviously an incredibly old question, but I'm experiencing a similar issue and was wondering if you resolved the issue?

Answer (score 7):

I believe there is no perfect way to place text with single-pixel precision on an image based on what `imagettfbbox()` returns and also using .ttf non-monospaced fonts. Over at the PHP manual many users have posted ways to accomplish this (with and without fudging the numbers); I recommend using [jodybrabec's simple function](http://es.php.net/manual/en/function.imagettfbbox.php#105593) over at the PHP manual, which calculates the exact bounding box. I have tested this one and only in extreme cases is the text positioned at most 1 pixel off in one direction. Nonetheless, if you add some padding (even if it is just 2 or 3 pixels) to your image your text will be within the dimensions of the image 100% of the time.

Comment: This does not answer my question.  I already cited the workarounds in the php.net comments in my question, and this answer is simply pointing me to one of those same workarounds.  I don't accept that the GD library is unable to determine a correct bounding box, since tons of other libraries are able to do the same thing without this quirk.  There's either a native solution (including possibly that I'm misunderstanding how these functions work), or something is broken in the PHP implementation.

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you don't subtract one from each of the dimensions in this line:

```
imagefilledrectangle($image, 0, 0, $boxWidth - 1, $boxHeight - 1, $color);
```

and instead do this:

```
imagefilledrectangle($image, 0, 0, $boxWidth, $boxHeight, $color);
```

Comment: I think this could be a comment?

Comment: I thought so too initially, but if it solves the issue, then it could work as an answer. Also, the formatting of the source code was a bit too restrictive for a comment. I opted for clarity so that it could be quickly understood.

Comment: `imagefilledrectangle()` creates the rectangle behind the text, not the actual text itself.  I merely do this to show the dimensions of what _should be_ the text's bounding box.  Subtracting 1 from the box's width/height is necessary because we need the absolute start/end pixels (e.g. for a 200x200px box, we want to draw a rectange from 0,0 to 199,199 inclusive).

Answer (score 0):

The [SlightlyMagic HQ Card Generator](http://www.slightlymagic.net/forum/viewtopic.php?f=30&t=465) project renders cards for the strategy card game Magic: the Gathering. The generator is powered by PHP with an advanced text rendering engine built in. I don't know about logic behind the calculations, but the renderer is dead accurate for the purposes of this application. Here's the function that calculates proper bounding boxes (`HQ Card Generator 8.x/scripts/classes/font.php`):

```
private function convertBoundingBox ($bbox) {
    // Transform the results of imagettfbbox into usable (and correct!) values.
    if ($bbox[0] >= -1)
        $xOffset = -abs($bbox[0] + 1);
    else
        $xOffset = abs($bbox[0] + 2);
    $width = abs($bbox[2] - $bbox[0]);
    if ($bbox[0] < -1) $width = abs($bbox[2]) + abs($bbox[0]) - 1;
    $yOffset = abs($bbox[5] + 1);
    if ($bbox[5] >= -1) $yOffset = -$yOffset;
    $height = abs($bbox[7]) - abs($bbox[1]);
    if ($bbox[3] > 0) $height = abs($bbox[7] - $bbox[1]) - 1;
    return array(
        'width' => $width,
        'height' => $height,
        'xOffset' => $xOffset, // Using xCoord + xOffset with imagettftext puts the left most pixel of the text at xCoord.
        'yOffset' => $yOffset, // Using yCoord + yOffset with imagettftext puts the top most pixel of the text at yCoord.
        'belowBasepoint' => max(0, $bbox[1])
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but this function is basically the same as those found in the php.net comments, and does exactly what I was not wanting to do -- it fudges the numbers by a pixel here and there to get them correct.  I want to know 1) why it's not correct to begin with, and possibly 2) how I can get it correct without hacky code like this.

Answer (score -1):

I know this is a little late but imagettfbbox is in points not pixels.

[pixel font size in imagettftext instead of point size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4357716/pixel-font-size-in-imagettftext-instead-of-point-size)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "imagettfbbox is in points not pixels".  If you meant that it returns coordinates in points, that's not correct (and would make no sense).  If you meant that the `$size` parameter is in points, not pixels, then that's not really relevant to my question (and also only true for GD2).